# Android play music cannot hear when opening for the first time

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-play-music

I am running Android 4.2-jelly-bean on cm10.1. When I start the play music, and play a song, it behaves as if the song is playing except there's no sound.

I have to exit the app, long press the home button, remove the play music from the list. Then only, I can hear the sound. Anybody else experiencing this problem? How to permanently fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Apollo player via `Settings > Apps > All > Apollo > and disable the Apollo player`? Restart phone, then see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Apollo is already disabled.